# can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' error with tkinter Entry

Tags: python-3.x, class, tkinter

I'm creating a game : The canon-man. You have to touch a target, specifying the angle and the velocity. The game is separated in 3 phases :

1- You choose "play", "options" or "quit"

2- You choose the difficulty "easy", "medium" or "hard"

3- The game appears and you can choose the parameters.

My game is separated in two classes, the first one(Canon) which handle the first and second phases and the second one(Man) which handle the third phase.

I can access the first two phases but when I click on "easy" "medium" or "hard"
I get this error :

" can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' "

and the third window appears like this (Tkinter's Entrys are not here) :

[third window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hss6x.png)

here is my class Man (a part of it) :

```
def base(self):

    self.height_c = 300
    self.width_c = 700

    self.choix = 0
    self.lang = 0

    self.flag = 0
    bool(self.flag)

    self.t = 0
    self.x = 130
    self.y = 225

    self.root = Tk()
    self.root.title("ShotDown")
    self.can = Canvas(self.root, width=self.width_c, height=self.height_c)
    self.can.grid(row=0, column=4, rowspan=4)

    self.cible = PhotoImage(file="\image\\cible.png")
    self.canon = PhotoImage(file="\image\\canon.png")
    self.canontete = PhotoImage(file="\image\\canontete.png")
    self.photo = PhotoImage(file="\image\\paysage_700.png")
    self.hc45 = PhotoImage(file="\image\hc45.png")
    self.Play = PhotoImage(file="\image\\Play.gif")

    self.angle = Entry(self.root, textvariable="hey")

    # initialisation:
    #

    # choix du fond

    if self.lang == "0000":

        self.photo = PhotoImage(file="\image\\paysage_700.png")

    elif self.lang == "0001":

        self.photo = PhotoImage(file="\image\\mer.png")

    elif self.lang == "0010":

        self.photo = PhotoImage(file="\image\\interstellar.png")

    self.y_cible = random.randint(60, 240)

    self.can.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=self.photo)
    self.image = self.can.create_image(-50, -50, image=self.hc45)

    # Creation des differents boutons
    #
    bou1 = Button(self.root, text='Quitter', width=8, command=self.root.quit)
    bou1.grid(row=0, column=2)

    bou2 = Button(self.root, text='Demarrer', width=8, command=Man.start_it(self))
    bou2.grid(row=0, column=3)

    bou3 = Button(self.root, text='Arreter', width=8, command=Man.stop_it)
    # bou3.grid(row=2, column=1)

    New_angle = StringVar()
    New_angle.set("Saisir Nouvel Angle")
    text_angle = Label(self.root, text="Angle :")
    text_angle.grid(row=1, column=2)
    self.angle = Entry(self.root, textvariable=New_angle)
    self.angle.grid(row=1, column=3)

    New_vitesse = StringVar()
    New_vitesse.set("Saisir Nouvelle Vitesse")
    text_vitesse = Label(self.root, text="Vitesse :")
    self.in_vitesse = Entry(self.root, textvariable=New_vitesse)
    text_vitesse.grid(row=2, column=2)
    self.in_vitesse.grid(row=2, column=3)

    bou_tir = Button(self.root, text='Tirer', width=8, command=Man.start_it(self))
    bou_tir.grid(row=0, column=3)

    if self.flag == 0:

        self.base = self.can.create_image(50, 260, image=self.canontete)
        self.can.create_image(self.width_c - 50, self.y_cible, image=self.cible)

    # demarrage de la boucle principale
    #

    self.root.mainloop()
```

If you don't understand something, feel free to ask ^^.

Thanks.

EDIT :

@calico_ " - Without seeing all of your code ". Sorry, I didn't show where the error was:

```
     self.can.update()
            b = float(self.angle.get() * pi / 180)
            Vo = float(self.in_vitesse.get())
            self.t += 0.025
            self.x += (Vo * cos(b) * self.t)
            self.y -= ((-0.5 * 9.81 * (self.t ** 2)) + (Vo * sin(b) * self.t))
            print(self.x, self.y)
```

Comment: There are several places in that code where you multiply two variables, do you know which specific line is causing the exception? For example, if `self.angle.get()` returns a sequence (maybe unintentionally), you cannot multiply it by `pi` because `pi` is probably a `float`.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing all of your code, or the complete exception, it is hard to tell you exactly whats wrong. But, here is an explanation of the error and likely why you're seeing it:

Sequences can be multiplied in Python. Here we create a list (a type of sequence), and then multiply it by 3:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> y = x*3
```

The result is not the product of each item by the factor. Rather, it is the original sequence three times:

```
>>> y
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Another piece of the puzzle - When you divide two numbers, the resulting value is usually a float, not an int:

```
>>> x = 6/3
>>> type(x)
<class 'float'>
```

And you **cannot** multiply a sequence by a float, only an integer. Exactly what the exception says..

So, look for a part of your code where you're multiplying sequences. The complete Traceback will help you find the lines causing the error. Just guessing, but what you probably want is list comprehension:

```
>>> y = [val*3 for val in x]
>>> y
[3, 6, 9]
```